# Can HTTP/1.1 Body contain a string like "\r\n"?

Tags: c, sockets, http

I'm trying to implement HTTP/1.1 protocol using Socket in C language. I just want to know if the Body inside a request can contain strings like: "\r\n" i.e a CR LF.

Also, please let me know if there is a maximum limit to the number of characters inside the body.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, the body can contain CRLFs. No, there is no limit to the length of the body.  The body is arbitrary data, as far as HTTP is concerned.  [RFC 2616 Section 4.4](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-4.4) outlines how to determine the length of the body and how the body is transmitted.  The `Content-Type` header determines how the body data is interpreted once received.

Answer (score 6):

There are no limits to the size or content of the body in an HTTP request or response.